# htaccess redirect from domain1 to domain2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know, this should be easy, but I cannot make it work.

I have 2 domains pointing to the same folder in an Apache server, bahiadivers.com and bahiadivers.cl.

I want to redirect bahiadivers.cl to bahiadivers.cl/es/ and change the address bar.

I try this (among a million things)

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bahiadivers.cl [nc]
rewriterule ^/$ http://www.bahiadivers.cl/es/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but didn't work... I mean, the URL is not changing in the browser address bar, but also the languge (/es/) is not working... how should I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your `.htaccess`

```
# Apache configuration file
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   # If URL is www.example.com/es/Blah, use /Blah/
   # Prevents needing to change existing links.
   RewriteBase /es/

   # Rewrite www.example.com to example.com
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bahiadivers.cl
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bahiadivers.cl
   # Rewrite any inbound URL Bits to http://bahiadivers.cl/es/...
   RewriteRule (.*) http://bahiadivers.cl/es/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

That should do it.

Comment: thanks stslavik, but it's not working... maybe my eyes are too tired already and cant find the problem...

Comment: WAIT, i think it's working and I have a problem when redirecting the other domain in my hosting...
What is not changing is the adress bar, shouldnt the [R] make the browser reload with the new url?
I mean, I want to see bahiadivers.cl/es/ instead of bahiadivers.cl.

Comment: add a # before RewriteBase then. I misunderstood whether or not you wanted the `es` visible.

Comment: In all fairness, I know it works because I ripped it directly from my site doing something similar.